# Why can't I lock a base class mutex from a derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, mutex

I have a base class B() with a member variable `pthread_mutex_t m`. When I try to lock the mutex from the derived class I block forever. I opened up GDB and printed what `m` looks like and it seems like gibberish (uninstantiated) but I'm not sure.

Base Class

```
class B
{
    protected: //or public!
        pthread_mutex_t m;

    public:
        virtual void lock(); //wrapper for pthread_mutex_lock(&m)
        virtual void unlock(); //wrapper
};
```

Derived Class

```
class D : B
{
    public:
        void foo();

    private:
        pthread_mutex_t derived_m;
};
```

And this is the code I have which blocks indefinitely.

```
D::foo() {
    //for reference below, gdb prints were taken here.

    pthread_mutex_lock(&m); //blocks forever
    pthread_mutex_lock(&derived_m); //okay
    lock(); //blocks forever
}
```

GDB print() for &m

```
$1 = {__data = {__lock = -8656, __count = 32767, __owner = 4198302, 
    __nusers = 0, __kind = 3, __spins = 0, __elision = 0, __list = {
      __prev = 0x400fed <__libc_csu_init+77>, __next = 0x0}}, 
  __size = "0\336\377\377\377\177\000\000\236\017@\000\000\000\000\000\003\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\355\017@", '\000' <repeats 12 times>, __align = 140737488346672}
```

GDB print() for &derived_m

```
$2 = {__data = {__lock = 0, __count = 0, __owner = -134225560, 
    __nusers = 32767, __kind = 14, __spins = 0, __elision = 0, 
    __list = {__prev = 0x400e7f <Logging::Logging(datastruct*)+67>, 
      __next = 0x7fffffffddc0}}, 
  __size = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000h\341\377\367\377\177\000\000\016\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\177\016@\000\000\000\000\000\300\335\377\377\377\177\000", __align = 0}
```

Comment: How are you initiating the mutex?

Comment: how are you creating D itself, stack or heap?

Comment: @user1937198 Both mutexes are initiated by declaring `pthread_mutex_t mymutex;`

Comment: @OlegBogdanov D is created on the stack.

Comment: Bad news, your mutexes are not initialized when declared

Comment: Also consider checkign the return value of @user1710278 that isnt initializing a mutex. You need to call `pthread_mutex_init` or assign `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` to your mutexes. See [this](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init). Also consider checking the return value of [`pthread_mutex_lock`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock)

Comment: Okay this makes sense. Thank you all!

Comment: @user1710278 Have you considered using std::mutex? Its API is much closer to what you where expecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mutex should be initialized first. There's two options to initialize a pthread mutex.

- Using the macro

  ```
  pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
  ```
- Using `pthread_mutex_init` function.

Please note that if you're using a `c++11` enabled compiler, you should use the standard `std` multithreading stuff, e.g. `std::mutex`.

Good starts:

- https://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2013/spring/12300-1/labs/lab6/

Comment: … and just for exposition, `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is almost certainly `{0}`.